# Error "This tab is not supported on your mobile" on adding webpart to Microsoft Teams when login through mobile

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, microsoft-teams

I have synced the spfx webpart with Microsoft Teams, it is working fine on the system but when trying to open the tab through mobile it is giving me an error "This tab is not supported on your mobile"....

As I am new to Sharepoint Framework, please suggest if there is an configuration required for this to be handled...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't miss any configuration requirements.

This capability is not yet supported in the Mobile client.